# Spherical Geometry inequalities with triangles using main formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, triangles, spherical-geometry

I'm having trouble with the following question from spherical geometry:

My book sets R=1.

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be the side lengths of a spherical triangle $ \triangle PQR$ and $a, b, c$ the opposite angles. Use the main formula:

$\cos \alpha = \cos \beta \cos \gamma + \sin  \beta \sin \gamma \cos a$

**to prove that $|\beta-\gamma|<\alpha <\beta + \gamma $,    and that $ \alpha +\beta +\gamma <  2 \pi $**

The second inequality follows by contradiction. Assume that  $ \alpha +\beta +\gamma =  2 \pi $, then using the angle sum formula for the cosine we find that:

$\cos \alpha = \cos \beta \cos \gamma - \sin  \beta \sin \gamma$

and that $cos(a)=-1$, this only happens for angle $\pi$. Which would contradict the fact that PQR is a triangle.  I notice that $\alpha <\beta + \gamma $ 
follows from the triangle inequality for metric spaces, the other side follows from inverse triangle inequality. $|\beta-\gamma|<\alpha $, but the last step is:

**Prove that three sides $\alpha, \beta, \gamma <\pi$, satisfying these two inequalities are sides of a spherical triangle.** Any pointers?